# Regular expression to explode the URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

When I am trying to explode the url from one string, its not returning the actual URL. Please find the def I have used

```
def self.getUrlsFromString(str="")
    url_regexp = /(?:http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?:(?::[0-9]{1,5})?\/[^\s]*)?/ix
    url        = str.split.grep(url_regexp)
    return url
rescue Exception =>  e
    DooDooLogger.log(e.message,e)
    return ""
end
```

when I do `self.getUrlsFromString(" check this site...http://``lnkd.in/HjUVii")` it's returning

> site...http://lnkd.in/HjUVii

Instead of

> http://lnkd.in/HjUVii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because grep in Array class returns an array of every element for element === pattern, so

```
str.split.grep(/http/ix)
```

will return ["site...http://lnkd.in/HjUVii"] too.

You can try instead of

```
str.split.grep(url_regexp)
```

something like this:

```
url_regexp.match(str).to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not you use something much simpler as regex like:

```
/((http|https):[^\s]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all occurences in a string, you could use `String#scan`:

```
str = "check these...http://lnkd.in/HjUVii http://www.google.com/"

str.scan(url_regexp)
=> ["http://lnkd.in/HjUVii", "http://www.google.com/"]
```